# Doing Counts based on timestamps

Tags: sql, sql-server, timestamp

I have a query that gives me the following results. This result set contains the times when jobs on a server started as well as when they finished.

```
JobName             LatestStartTime         LatestEndTime
Job1                2016-04-15 00:00:40.000 2016-04-15 00:07:40.000
Job2                2016-04-15 00:01:23.000 2016-04-15 00:17:37.000
Job3                2016-04-15 08:00:03.000 2016-04-15 08:18:05.000
Job4                2016-04-15 08:30:06.000 2016-04-15 08:57:21.000
Job5                2016-04-15 09:00:03.000 2016-04-15 09:07:49.000
Job6                2016-04-15 03:53:40.000 2016-04-15 03:53:41.000
Job7                2016-04-15 09:30:07.000 2016-04-15 11:36:35.000
```

On the other hand, I have a query that creates a temp table with 15 min intervals. As the following:

```
Increment
2016-04-15 00:00:00.000
2016-04-15 00:15:00.000
2016-04-15 00:30:00.000
2016-04-15 00:45:00.000
2016-04-15 01:00:00.000
2016-04-15 01:15:00.000
2016-04-15 01:30:00.000
2016-04-15 01:45:00.000
2016-04-15 02:00:00.000
2016-04-15 02:15:00.000
2016-04-15 02:30:00.000
2016-04-15 02:45:00.000
```

I want to know which jobs run at a determined increment. For example, my final result set should look something like:

```
Increment                     NumberOfJobs    JobNames
2016-04-15 00:00:00.000       2               Job1, Job2
2016-04-15 00:15:00.000       1               Job2
2016-04-15 00:30:00.000       0               NULL
```

OR

```
Increment                     NumberOfJobs    JobNames
2016-04-15 00:00:00.000       2               Job1
2016-04-15 00:00:00.000       2               Job2

2016-04-15 00:15:00.000       1               Job2
2016-04-15 00:30:00.000       0               NULL
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difficult part is getting the list of jobs on a single row.  The counts are easy:

```
select t.increment, j.jobname,
       sum(count(*)) over (partition by t.increment) as countOfJobs
from times t left join
     jobs j
     on t.increment >= j.lasteststarttime and
        t.increment <= j.lastestendtime
group by t.increment, j.jobname
order by increment, jobname;
```

Getting the list requires a weird subquery in SQL Server:

```
select t.increment, count(*) as numJobs,
       stuff((select ', ' + j2.jobname
              from jobs j2
              where t.increment >= j2.lasteststarttime and
                    t.increment <= j2.lastestendtime
              for xml path ('')
             ), 1, 1, '') as jobs
from times t  left join
         jobs j
         on t.increment >= j.lasteststarttime and
            t.increment <= j.lastestendtime
group by t.increment
order by increment;
```

If the job names contain unusual characters (those that need escaping for XML), then the XML logic is slightly more complex.  That seems unlikely for job names, though.

Comment: you get wrong result, to get right jobs after intervals you need `SELECT Max([increment]) AS t FROM temp_table WHERE [increment] < q.LatestStartTime`

Comment: Thank you! This query just did what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
SELECT [increment], JobName
, Count(1) over (Partition by [increment]) AS NumberOfJobs    
FROM temp_table
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT JobName, st.t AS t1, LatestEndTime AS t2
  FROM query AS q
  OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT Max([increment]) AS t 
    FROM temp_table 
    WHERE [increment] < q.LatestStartTime) as st
  ) as j ON Increment BETWEEN j.t1 and j.t2
```

it returns:

```
increment   JobName NumberOfJobs
2016-04-15 00:00:00.000 Job1    2
2016-04-15 00:00:00.000 Job2    2
2016-04-15 00:15:00.000 Job2    1
2016-04-15 02:45:00.000 Job3    5
2016-04-15 02:45:00.000 Job4    5
2016-04-15 02:45:00.000 Job5    5
2016-04-15 02:45:00.000 Job6    5
2016-04-15 02:45:00.000 Job7    5
```

with the left join :

```
SELECT [increment], JobName
, Count(JobName) over (Partition by [increment]) AS NumberOfJobs    
FROM temp_table
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT JobName, st.t AS t1, LatestEndTime AS t2
  FROM query AS q
  OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT Max([increment]) AS t 
    FROM temp_table 
    WHERE [increment] < q.LatestStartTime) as st
  ) as j ON Increment BETWEEN j.t1 and j.t2
```

returns:

```
2016-04-15 00:00:00.000 Job1    2
2016-04-15 00:00:00.000 Job2    2
2016-04-15 00:15:00.000 Job2    1
2016-04-15 00:30:00.000 NULL    0
2016-04-15 00:45:00.000 NULL    0
2016-04-15 01:00:00.000 NULL    0
2016-04-15 01:15:00.000 NULL    0
2016-04-15 01:30:00.000 NULL    0
2016-04-15 01:45:00.000 NULL    0
2016-04-15 02:00:00.000 NULL    0
2016-04-15 02:15:00.000 NULL    0
2016-04-15 02:30:00.000 NULL    0
2016-04-15 02:45:00.000 Job3    5
2016-04-15 02:45:00.000 Job4    5
2016-04-15 02:45:00.000 Job5    5
2016-04-15 02:45:00.000 Job6    5
2016-04-15 02:45:00.000 Job7    5
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  *,
        COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY increment) numberOfJobs
FROM    times
JOIN    jobs
ON      increment BETWEEN latestStartTime AND latestEndTime
```